# Conda can't update packages after using conda forge add channel command

Tags: python, conda, conda-forge

I downloaded and installed the newest Ananconda distribution normally, and gave it these commands in the prompt:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Now, nothing works right when I try to update or install packes.  I get this error over and over again.

```
conda update --all
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
```

I've even reinstalled anaconda, deleted all old folders, etc.  The command line gets to the third "Solving environment:" sequence, and it just spins.  I have to manually stop it with Ctrl-C.  What is going on here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anaconda base isn't practically compatible with making Conda Forge the priority channel. Users wanting Conda Forge prioritized should prefer a Miniforge base.